# INSERT INTO MySQL table SELECT FROM PostgreSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a Amazon Redshift table which runs on PostgreSQL.This table is updated everyday with user data in large numbers.

I have to run a CRON process to import some of the needed data from the table everyday into a different MySQL database . I work in PHP.Please assist me how I could achieve this programatically.

Comment: Sorry mallik SO **is not a free coding resource** You have to start the process and then if you have specific issues with a finite piece of code we are more than willing to help. **But we do not work from spec's**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should export from Redshift to an S3 bucket using the UNLOAD command, then load that file (CSV is a good choice) into MySQL. This can all be done from a cron job. It is by far the fastest and safest way of doing it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

P.S.
Redshift does not really "run on PostgresSQL". Sure, Redshift was a fork of Postgres, but the two are completely different beasts.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried fetching a data from postgress db and create an array from that and there after with the help of that array insert that in mysql. (I am assuming you are familiar with the syntax of how postgress and mysql queries)

Comment: Yes I had that idea in mind , but since the data is quite large(~1,00,000 rows x 10 cols),is it recommended to store in temporary variables.

Comment: no it s not recommended to store that in variable as that would have memory limit issues, instead fetch that in chunks of 250 records at a time from each table and execute cron with a shorter difference may be of per minute so that there would not be much change in the postgress db